# How to add an image to a table using Visual Basic and ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have an html table with rows being generated in a For loop and I want to place an image in the first column of each row, but everything I have tried just shows "System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image" in the first column of each row and then one of the images below the table.

I've never really tried anything like this using images before, so I am kind of lost. You can see a few things commented out where I tried different things with no luck.

ASP:

```
<asp:Image ID="img_Circle" runat="server"  Width ="10%" Height ="10%"></asp:Image>
```

VB:

```
lblTickets.Text = "<table><tr><th></th><th>Summary</th><th>Status</th></tr>"

    For Each ticket In tickets

        Dim issue As Issue = jiraApp.GetIssue(ticket)

        'Dim statusimage As Image

        Dim statusname As String

        If issue.Status = 3 Then

            'btn_Circle.ImageUrl = "~/m/i/Circle_Green.png"

            'statusimage = "~/m/i/Circle_Green.png"

            img_Circle.ImageUrl = "~/m/i/Circle_Green.png"

            statusname = "Complete"

        Else

            'btn_Circle.ImageUrl = "~/m/i/Circle_Red.png"

            'statusimage = "~/m/i/Circle_Red.png"

            img_Circle.ImageUrl = "~/m/i/Circle_Red.png"

            statusname = "Incomplete"

        End If

        lblTickets.Text &= String.Format("<tr><th>{0}</th><td>{1}</td><td>{2}</td></tr>", img_Circle, issue.Summary, statusname)


    Next

    lblTickets.Text &= "</table>"
```

Comment: `img_Circle` is an Object of Type `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image` and so you can't assign it as text in `String.Format` and expect it to display the image. If you really want to manually write out the HTML using your `String.Format` just ditch the `<asp:Image` and build standard `img` tags in your loop to include in the `String.Format`

Comment: @mjw That makes complete sense. I feel pretty dumb about now. Thanks for the help!